# Can the nullspace of a $3\times 6$ or $6\times 5$ matrix be a $3$-dimensional vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

More specifically:

1) could the nullspace of a $3\times 6$ matrix be a vector space of dimension $3$ that is contained in $\mathbb{R}^5$

2) could the nullspace of a $6 \times 5$ matrix be a vector space of dimension $3$ that is contained in $\mathbb{R}^5$

I thought yes and no respectively, because for 1) the $3\times 6$ could have $3$ linearly independent $3$-tuples, and then the remaining columns could be rearranged and form a basis for a nullspace which would have dimension $3$, and then for 2) the nullspace would be made of $6$-tuples, which aren't in $\mathbb{R}^5$
.

But I've heard that the answer is actually no and yes, so I'm probably wrong.

Comment: Are you asking wether or not their exists such linear transformations?

Comment: I mean does there exist a 3x6/6x5 matrix whose nullspace is a vector space of dimension 3 which is contained in R5

Comment: It also depends if you assume the matrices acts on the left on column vectors or on the right on row vectors, although I hove the impression mostly the former is used.

Answer (score 1):

By the rank-nullity theorem, the answer is actually yes for both. However, the null space is contained in $\mathbb{R}^6$ and not $\mathbb{R}^5$ as you state. This is because, $3\times6$ and $6\times5$ matrices take a $6$ dimensional space to $3$ dimensional space and $5$ dimensional space to $6$ dimensional space. Hence,there can be the chance of the null space dimension or nullity to be a $3$-dimensional space.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. could the nullspace of a 3x6 matrix be a vector space of dimension 3 that is contained in R5

No. The null space of a 3 x 6 matrix is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^6$. And, the nullity of $A$ could be 3. However, this null space is *not* contained in $\mathbb{R}^5$, because $\mathbb{R}^6$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}^5$ (and $\mathbb{R}^5$ is *not* a subset of $\mathbb{R}^6$). And so, with the way the question is posed, my answer would be no.

> 2. could the nullspace of a 6x5 matrix be a vector space of dimension 3 that is contained in R5

Yes. The null space of a 3 x 6 matrix is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^5$. And, the nullity of $A$ could be 3.